# Permission to access emails and facebook

Tags: facebook

I create a app that use login on Facebook, but I can not capture the user's email address, I know I need to use scope, but do not know how. How can I do this?
This is my code:

> ```
>  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>   FB.init({
>      appId      : '<?= $this->getAppId(); ?>', // App ID
>      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
>      status     : true, // check login status
>      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
>      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
>      oauth     : true
>
>    });
>    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
>      // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
>      if (response.status === 'connected') {
>         testAPI();
>      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
>        FB.login()
>      } else {
>         FB.login()
>
>      }
>    });
>    }
>
>    // Load the SDK asynchronously
>    (function(d){
>     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
>     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
>     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
>     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
>    }(document));
>
>    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
>    // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
>    function testAPI() {
>      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
>      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
>        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
>        console.log( response.email);
>      });
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, when use FB.Event.subscribe, we need put the permissions in html and not in FB.login() function, using  this way:

> fb:login-button show-faces="true" perms="email,user_birthday" width="200" max-rows="1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You pass in any additional permissions you want as an argument (comma-separated for multiple permissions) to `FB.login()`. IN your case, you want `email`:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

The [FB JS SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) **very clearly** explains this. Please take the time to read it.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble. But I tried but did not work, I believe the way I did requires a different way to use the scope. What Do you think about?